# Windows Forms UserControl + Panel: WPF Equivalent

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, tweetsharp

In Windows Forms, I have created a Twitter application that gets the latest tweets from the Timeline using TweetSharp. I have used a `UserControl` and a `Panel` to display these. The code I've used to do this looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> tweets = service.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline();

foreach (var tweet in tweets)
{
    TweetBox t = new TweetBox();

    t.username.Text = tweet.User.ScreenName; // Label
    t.display.ImageLocation = tweet.User.ProfileImageUrl; // PictureBox
    t.tweet.Text = tweet.Text; // Label
    t.info.Text = tweet.CreatedDate.ToString();
    t.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    HomeTimeline.Controls.Add(t); // Add to HomeTimeline Panel
}
```

I'm now re-making this application in WPF. The UserControl is in the same format, but I'm clueless as of how to add this to the panel and dock it to the top - or the equivalent in WPF. How do I do this?

Comment: Have a look at the ItemsControl.

Comment: Yuck, a foreach-loop, have a look at [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [data templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A WinForms UserControl are not the same as a WPF UserControl.

You'll have to make the UserControl again, in WPF.

Of course, you could wrap the WinForms UserControl in a `WindowsFormsHost` element, but that's not good practice.

Comment: The user control I have is a wpf user control

Comment: Must have overlooked that. Anyway, GUI in WPF is done in XAML. (Although it can be done in code-behind, it's not good practice either)